# Generators of Lorentz Transformation (Dirac Spinor)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

Starting from the transformation law for the classical Dirac field
under Lorentz transformations $x \rightarrow ax$ and $\psi(x) \rightarrow \psi\prime(x\prime) = S(a)\psi(x) $ I will derive the generators of these transformations. Now I am a bit confused since I read following.

$\psi\prime(x\prime)$ and $\psi(x)$ should have the same value, so that $\psi\prime(x\prime) = \psi(x)$
should be true. I have this from here (https://portal.uni-freiburg.de/ag-dittmaier/lectures/archive/QFT14/qft.pdf, Eq.2.51 on page 20) 
If this is true, S(a) should be the identity matrix?

Nevertheless, the conclusion from $\psi\prime(x\prime) = \psi(x)$ is that $\psi\prime(x) = S(a)\psi(a^{-1}x)$

For infinitesimal transformation we have $\psi\prime(x) = (1 - \frac{i}{4} \sigma_{\mu\nu})\psi(a^{-1}x)$ and $\psi(a^{-1}x) \approx (1 - \omega_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu}\partial_{\nu})\psi(x)$ where I used for $a: a^{\mu}_{\nu} = g^{\mu}_{\nu} + w^{\mu}_{\nu}$

At the end I get  $\psi\prime(x) = (1 - \frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu})\psi(x)\rightarrow \psi\prime(x) = e^{\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu}}\psi(x)$

Its not that important how $M_{\mu\nu}$ looks like, but what is also confusing for me is that this $M_{\mu\nu}$ should be the generators of the transformation. But this equation $\psi\prime(x) = e^{\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu}}\psi(x)$ is not of the form $\psi\prime(x\prime) = S(a)\psi(x) $, thus $e^{\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu}} \not= S(a)$. Why are $M_{\mu\nu}$ still the generators?

Comment: Why are you using $a$ to represent a Lorentz transformation matrix? Nobody does that. The usual symbol is $\Lambda$.

Comment: you are right, our prof is using it so i am used to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nevertheless, the conclusion from ψ′(x′)=ψ(x) is that
>   ψ′(x)=S(a)ψ(a−1x)

The departing point is:

$\Psi'(x') = S(\Lambda)\Psi(x)$

As $x' = \Lambda x$ => $\Psi'(x') = S(\Lambda)\Psi(\Lambda^{-1}x')$

Or renaming the independent variable:
$\Psi'(x) = S(\Lambda)\Psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$

$\Psi'(x') = \Psi(x)$ only for scalar fields.

Comment: Ok this is helpful. Thanks
But $\psi\prime(x) = e^{\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu}}\psi(x)$ is not of the form $\psi\prime(x) = S(a)\psi(a^{-1}x) $, thus $e^{\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu}} \not= S(a)$. So why are $M_{\mu\nu}$ the generators?

Comment: Because $\Psi(\Lambda^{−1}x)≈(1−\omega_{\mu \nu} x^\nu \partial \nu)\Psi (x)$ as you mentioned in your post.